# How to create Synapse External table for Dynamics365 Finance and Operations table

Tags: azure-synapse, dynamics-365

I have a Data Lake in Azure Synapse, where is made table from Dynamics365 Finance and Operations - CustTable.

Data Lake structure:

```
xxx
- Tables
-- Common
--- Customer
---- Main
     CustTable.cdm.json
     config.json
     Main.manifest.cdm.json
----- CustTable
      CUSTTABLE_00001.csv
      index.json
```

Data file CUSTTABLE_00001.csv does not contain header.

How to create External Table CustTable, with correct header and column format configuration? Is the only way to do it manually?

It looks like file CustTable.cdm.json contains header configuration.

I made External Table in Synapse New SQL Script > Create external table, but it doesn't make script with correct header and column configuration.

Example:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[test] (
    [C1] bigint,
    [C2] nvarchar(100),
    [C3] nvarchar(100),
```

Is it possible to make External Table conveniently?

Comment: Are you using the Azure Synapse Dataverse connector?

Comment: @Jon, I am new to this and as I understand from our IT then Dataverse is used for connection Dynamics365-FO -> Synapse Data Lake. Did you mean this connection?

Comment: Yes, using the synapse link, D365 dumps data to the data lake, in Synapse it will auto create the external tables. Otherwise you'll have to manually create the external table with the column names. If you are just exporting csv to the data lake, check the D365 export jobs to add in headers. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/data-platform/azure-synapse-link-synapse

Comment: @Jon, we will check this and I let you know about results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your data file does not contain a header, you need to define the column names in the External Table script manually only in Synapse SQL pools. There is no option to infer the column names and type from `CustTable.cdm.json` file in the external table script.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[CustTable]
(
    [Field1] [datatype],
    [Field2] [datatype],
    [Field3] [datatype],
    ...
)
WITH
(
    LOCATION = 'CustTable_00001.csv',
    DATA_SOURCE = <your_data_lake_data_source>,
    FILE_FORMAT = <your_file_format>
)
```

Here replace `<field1>` and `<datatype>` with the required values from config file.

Comment: Is it possible in this scenario (Dynamics365-FO -> Data Lake) to get files with header row?

Comment: I am not aware of copying the header along with data from Dynamics 365 to Data lake. You can use ADF dataflow and merge the metadata file with csv data file.